# Should I use mb_* or iconv_* functions for multibyte strings?

Tags: php, unicode, multibyte, iconv

As we all now, handling multibyte strings is not that easy in PHP. For example I want to get the length of the following string: `ä`

```
strlen('ä'); // 2, because ä equals 2 bytes
mb_strlen('ä', 'UTF-8'); // 1
iconv_strlen('ä', 'UTF-8'); // 1
```

Which functions should I use? The mb_* or iconv_*?  Why? Considering that the encoding may not be limited to UTF-8.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this Powerpoint presentation:

http://www.nyphp.org/content/presentations/smallworld/April2006-nyphp-Presentation.ppt

In a nutshell: 
Iconv supports more encodings, but is less portable.

From the presentation:

> PHP supports multi byte in two
>   extensions: iconv  and mbstring
>
> - iconv uses an external library (supports more encodings but less
>     portable)
> - mbstring has the library bundled with PHP (less encodings but more
>     portable)

Comment: thx! another pro for mbstring is, that there are a lot more functions like mb_strtoupper, mb_strtolower, etc.